# Super-generic Fantasy World: The problem with Murder Hobos

Tags: society, military, economy

***Murder Hobo*** is a pejorative and very descriptive term. It refers to the player types or a band of those player types, who are basically homeless serial killers, responsible for ruining the currency of entire countries, and destroying tons of ancient archeological sites.

---

**Enforcer:** Directed-Energy weapons used by the Foundation's Mobile Task Force known as the "Protectors". It has three major modes, each of them is ranged:

- Non-lethal, Paralyzer
- Lethal, Eliminator
- Anti-material, Decomposer

---

*Accessing requested document: Adventurer_P001.doc...*
*Access granted*

=====Class 2 File================================================

**Item #:** SCP-P001
**Object Class:** Euclid|Neutral|Memetic

**Special Containment Procedures:** Instances of SCP-P001 referred to as SCP-P001-A are to be contained in a Standard-Humanoid containment room, adjusted to the species of SCP-P001-A. Uncontained instances are to be captured with the Enforcer's Non-Lethal mode.

**Description:** SCP-P001 is never directly observed, but its existence is proven. SCP-P001 appears to be affecting sapient beings in a yet unknown, way turning them into instances of SCP-P001-A.

Intel on SCP-P001-A is rather scarce and varies between individual instance, however, few trait are generally observed:

- Instances of SCP-P001-A retain their personalities, however, during interrogations, all instances recall a `voice in their head that tells them what to do`. Researches conducted in the communication with these voices, from here referred to as SCP-P001-B, met with success.
- SCP-P001-B appears to be a subconscious phenomenon, wich is unique in each specimen displaying the personalities of various dead humans from Earth.
- While remaining unclear, SCP-P001 seems to affect specimens of all races, regardless their biological buildup or mental state, however, the races, SCP-P003-B *"Gully Dwarves"* and SCP-P004 *"Kender"* (except for SCP-P004-B *"Afflicted Kender"*) have orders of magnitudes lower numbers in affected individuals.
- SCP-P001 usually affects individuals from their society's middle class.
- Testings conducted on SCP-P001-B reveal, that all SCP-P001-B instance has remarkably high knowledge on chemistry, geology, biology, military tactics, and classical physics, capable of accurately predicting the likely outcome of various mechanical interactions.
- Instances of SCP-P001-A have shown signs of a "telepathic link" that enables them to execute coordinated team movements under minimal time with high rate of success.
- SCP-P001-A seems to be highly affected by their SCP-001-B, test subjects often show signs of apathy, general disregard for self-preservation instincts, and an unknown motivation to organize themselves into five-member parties.

**SCP-█████'s theory:**

Based on the collected intel, that I can't use to [DATA EXPUNGED] the O5-Council, it's likely that instances of SCP-P001-B are indeed humans, this suggests that connection between our world and [DATA REDACTED] already existed, prior to the recovery of SCP-P000. If their statements are proven to be true, that would mean that [DATA REDACTED] exists, and it's a bunch of pissed off nerds. (Wich would be worse than... THE BRIGHT FAMILY REUNION.)

---

*(The "question":)*
**You**, the SCP-Analytical team, **must create a simulation to estimate the potential levels of danger, SCP-P001 poses.**

**The threat is threefold:**

- **Economic threat:** In [DATA REDACTED], most governments are loosely feudal with having independent villages and cities, as the base of the economy and army reserves, under the nobility's watch. 
  The technological level is strongly reminiscent to that of medieval Europe, suggesting that [DATA REDACTED].
- **Social threat:** instances of SCP-P001-A usually have modern day idea-sets, such as equal-opportunity, anti-racism, democracy, und so weiter... (and so on...). 2% of the population, of the currently observed locations, gets converted into instances of SCP-P001-A, each year.
- **Physical threat:** Parties of SCP-P001-A prefer military tactics over outdated, honor-based ones. The combination of this, and their telepathic links makes them the most hard-hitting paramilitary force in [DATA REDACTED], only rivaled by the Mobile Task Forces and the army of [DATA REDACTED], but due to outside pressure, [DATA REDACTED]'s military forces are restricted to a negligibly small area of operation.

---

Good Luck, and remember:

SCP stands for: **S**ecure **C**ontain **P**rotect,
and not:        **S**porting **C**lube de **P**ortugal

=====Class 2 File================================================
*You are the analytical team, you know what's the question, and you've been provided with everything we know about this world and SCP-P001, make your estimates based on these.*

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: @apaul34208 To create an estimation of the potential dangers, SCP-P001-A pose to a semi-feudal society.

Comment: @apaul34208 It's now written in question format, but it should be obvious, what I mean by the question, and what I expect in the answers (the aforementioned analytical team's work).

Comment: That's still really broad, and sounds like you're looking for story development or future forecasting rather than a specific worldbuilding element.

Comment: @apaul34208 I have to say that the question is very cleverly written.  Don't get frustrated, but twist your mind a bit and it becomes abundantly clear, kind of like those magic 3d pictures.  :)  well played Redacted Redacted.  Lets have some fun with this!

Comment: @PaulTIKI  https://youtu.be/BDoC8BhtUyo Happy Easter ;)

Comment: Nice!  well played, sir!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

SCP-P001-B Neutralization program log:

Simulate effectiveness of tracking potential subjects.

The SCP-P001-B appears to exist in a separate dimension with a time-stream different from our own.  While the link is continuous in our dimension, extended periods of time can pass on the other side.

More data needs to be collected, but preliminary analysis suggests that the telepathic link is developed through the use of specialized Tomes.  There are a variety of these kinds of tomes, but further research suggests that they are mass produced.

The link is further strengthened by objects that are polyhedral and marked on each surface by sequentially valued symbols.

With this information we need to establish what technologies need to be improved or developed in order to track or contain SCP-P001-B

A method of transmitting data between dimensions.  A self sustaining transmitter small enough to be hidden within the Tomes or associated Polyhedra.

---

*next log entry*

MIcroscopic audio/video transmitters have been introduced into the production facilities that create the Tomes and Polyhedra.

This has created a much broader data-set than was previously possible.

SCP-P001-B are, indeed, *homo sapiens* but seem to have common (but not necessarily exclusive) traits.  They tend to be adolescent to young adult.  They are mostly male.  They tend to be less physically imposing than the norm.

Also noted is the tendency to be equally interested in reading works of both science and fiction.  "Jay-Ar-Ar Toll-Kin" is a commonly used word, but we have not been able to determine more about this phonetic sequence. (see also "Jorj-Ar-Ar-Mar-Ten")

Subjects also tend to get confused when in the presence of female *H. Sapiens* unless the female already existed in the social group from pre-adolescence.  Exposure to females seems to cause elevated heart rate, sweat production, and a marked *decrease* in verbal communication ability.

---

*log continues*

It has been observed that SCP-P001-B is generally unaware of the telepathic links.  They are convinced that it is a part of their "imagination" We have now seen evidence that this link can happen even without the Tome and Polyhedra.

Subjects are using their "imagination" to let out deep psychological manifestations that may have origins in feelings of inadequacy, powerlessness, and curiously, suppressed sexuality.  This leads to the damaging behaviors in SCP-P001-A.

---

*log entry in progress*
Recommendation:  Until we can find a way to disrupt the telepathic signal, we can do some things to mitigate the worst effects on SCP-P001-A...

*how can I say this to command?  Get these kids a date?  There is an idea, see if we can distract them with girls.  Maybe we could try some sort of economic manipulation to put the producers of Tomes and Polyhedra out of business. If we could take out this "Wizards of the Coast"  we might have fewer problems.*

Use of Force should not be required.  The core of the problem is that as long as imagination exists, we will continue to see these telepathic links get established.

Focus needs to be on interfering with the signal.
*Darn Murder Hobos*

Comment: Lets not forget the suspicion of Vin Diesel as a potential SCP-P001-B.  Further investigation has revealed that increasing numbers of female -B's are rendering the interference of "girls" on the signal to be less pronounced.

Comment: Additional reports are now coming in of small armies spontaneously appearing in the countryside.  The are characterized by first the appearance of a Wizard (they refer to themselves as 'planeswalkers') followed by the increasingly progressive appearance of small armies.  These armies fight until one or the other 'planeswalker' gets killed and then both armies disappear, leaving large swaths of land heavily damaged.  Fortunately this only seems to happen around Swamps, Mountains, Forests, Plains, and sometimes in Island chains.  Wizards of the Coast is suspected.

Comment: Also, ongoing settlement in Cataan is going to cause an overpopulation problem soon

Comment: Speculation: Ar-Ar is some form of grading or cathegorising system.

Comment: All it would categorize is gruesome death, based on the context.